# How to distinguish between mouse click and touch tap

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Does the OpenLayers 3 interface provide any mechanism to determine if a click, dblclick, or singleclick was triggered by a mouse versus a touch event? I looked at ol.has.TOUCH but just because a browser supports touch doesn't mean that the user isn't using a mouse so that doesn't meet my needs.

I'm sending the click-ed coordinates to my server and finding that the mouse clicks are typically more precise that the touch taps so I would like to adjust tolerances based on which fired the click.

Comment: It's very hard to trigger `click` on touch device(because it doesn't even allow 
1 pixel point difference). so wasn't it enough to set click for mouse click event?

Comment: @Chase Choi I am not having trouble getting the click event on the touch device, but I find that the position (coordinates) of the click are less precise when it comes from a touch devise instead of a mouse, so I want to adjust my tolerances based on what device generated the click event.

Answer (score 1):

The click event object has `evt.pointerEvent.pointerType` and `evt.originalEvent.pointerType` which in my limited testing are set to "mouse" or "touch". This seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I don't know if `evt.pointerEvent.pointerType` or `evt.originalEvent.pointerType` is prefered.